Remove wget argument from Yocto do_fetch
I'm using Yocto Mickledore, and my build fails on the do_fetch of multiple python libraries.
The log files show that the use of --passive-ftp as a wget argument is to blame.
DEBUG: Fetcher accessed the network with the command /usr/bin/env wget -t 2 -T 30 --passive-ftp -O /home/{username}/Documents/Yocto/poky/build/downloads/Flask-2.2.3.tar.gz.tmp -P /home/{username}/Documents/Yocto/poky/build/downloads 'https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/source/F/Flask/Flask-2.2.3.tar.gz'
Unknown option 'passive-ftp'

Setting passive-ftp=no in .wgetrc had no effect.
How can I tell bitbake to not use the --passive-ftp argument?

I was able to update the wget command used by Yocto, with this line added to my local.conf.
FETCHCMD_wget = "/usr/bin/wget"

Yocto is now able to fetch the needed files.

Mickledore is out of support so hasn't been getting fixes. See https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Releases
This issue was fixed in supported versions in April with this change:
https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/commit/?id=c0cd7a6d3b2413dbaa91d319e07fea34bf02e67d
You likely ran into this by using a recent host Distro with an older release. Using an older host Distro would also likely work around the issue since older versions of wget ignored that option which is why this used to work.
